# Battery charging directly from DC source

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

We are having Lithium-Ion battery with below specification,

Charging voltage - 16.8V
Charging Current - 1.38A avg; 3.45A max

If we provide above voltage and current from a regulated power supply directly to batteries +ve & -Ve will it charge properly without any issue.

Note: This battery internally having an BMS.

Kindly clarify

Comment: A BMS is not a charger and should not be relied upon to act as one. Use a proper charger.

Comment: that sounds fine according to the limited info provided, a lot of packs have all the charging circuity on-board, but providing the model of the battery would let us answer with detail and confidence.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.